# RMQ Pika threading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, rabbitmq

Pika states it is not [thread-safe](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions) and not to share one connection across multiple threads.

(I think) I am running one thread per connection which *should* be ok but the wording of other answers suggests that there may be a subtle difference in 'running one thread per connection' and 'running one connection per thread'.

My goal is to have a consumer that listens for RMQ messages and when a message is received, do some work which takes time. The work logic itself is not multithreaded as it executes 'synchronously'. The exchange and queue was setup manually - I am just writing a consumer.

However due to the fact that the work takes time (url calls), currently I have each callback create and execute a single thread;

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        name = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        print(f"Thread {name} execution started.")
        # Simulate URL calls
        time.sleep(random.randrange(1,5))
        print(f"Thread {name} execution ended.")


class MyClass():
    def connect(self, url, queue):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.connection.URLParameters(url)
        )
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.basic_consume(queue=queue, on_message_callback=self.callback)

        # Infinite loop that waits for incoming messages
        channel.start_consuming()


    def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        thread = MyThread()
        thread.start()
        # Not sure of this ACK and how to NACK
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

When executing the program the threads complete in different orders which is what I expect.

```
Thread H execution started.
Thread E execution started.
Thread G execution started.
Thread j execution started.
Thread E execution ended.
Thread j execution ended.
Thread H execution ended.
Thread G execution ended.
```

My understanding is that the following implementation (that I am not using) would cause thread safe issues;

```
def callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
    thread1 = MyThread()
    thread2 = MyThread()
    thread3 = MyThread()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
```

Is my implementation thread safe? If not, how would I implement a thread safe version?

**EDIT** I added my implementation of an ACK, I'm not sure how to implement `add_callback_threadsafe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears fine. When you acknowledge a message from the thread spawned by the callback, be sure to use [this method](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) that uses `add_callback_threadsafe`.

Comment: So I have to ACK and NACK within the thread that is spawned? And that means I have to pass the connection variable to the callback to the thread?

Comment: Yes. If you wait for the spawned thread to exit, then ack from the thread that owns the connection, you block Pika's I/O loop. If you use `SelectConnection` you have much finer control over the interaction with the I/O loop than with `BlockingConnection`

Comment: If my consumer crashes for whatever reason outside of the thread logic (before spawning a thread) I assume using 'global' exception handling to return a basic NACK (if I don't use autoack) is considered safe?